# Set credentials to connect another computer .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm  trying to copy a file with the command :

```
 File.Copy(source, dest, true);
```

when "dest" is address of remote computer . 
When I run this command i got error that "Access to path is denied".

I understood that the problem is caused by the fact that i didn't have permission to the remote computer, so I want to connect to the remote computer before I trying to copy the file.

How can I log in and set the credentials to the computer using .NET Core?

thank you.

Comment: I think you have to add a user on remote computer with specific username and password and impersonating the user before copying file.

Comment: I'n not sure, but you can look at `NamedPipes` which commonly is used for Network Interprocess Communication. It allows you send messages as `byte[]` between different processes.

Comment: @Aria how can I add user to remote computer?